# d3v4 multi-line chart domain setting and animations

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I was converting an old version d3 line chart and I'm trying to improve the input data so its the domain is calculated properly.

//current version 4
https://jsfiddle.net/497tmhu0/3/

```
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

            y.domain([
                d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.temperature; }); }),
                d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.temperature; }); })
            ]);
```

to use one json set - and to correct the code is this calculation of the x domain correct?

```
            x.domain([
                d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.date; }); }),
                d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.date; }); })
            ]);
```

---

- I am keen to merge the data input into a cleaner ONE source type situation.
- Also change the structure to a more -- label, value - naming convention then be specific in "temperature" -- like "San Francisco" should be a label
- Fix the x axis it appears broken or the ticks oddly formatted
- Fix the text drop off occuring on the end of the lines -- possibly cut from the edges of the chart - maybe just a change in the margin -- "right: 55"

  ```
          var data = [{
            "date": "20111003",
            "New York": 53.3,
            "San Francisco": 22.8
          }, {
            "date": "20111004",
            "New York": 55.7,
            "San Franciscok": 38.8
          }, {
            "date": "20111005",
            "New York": 55.7,
            "San Franciscok": 38.8
          }];


          var cities = [{
            "id": "New York",
            "values": [{
              "date": 20111003,
              "temperature": 34
            }, {
              "date": 20111004,
              "temperature": 42
            }, {
              "date": 20111005,
              "temperature": 23
            }]
          }, {
            "id": "San Francisco",
            "values": [{
              "date": 20111003,
              "temperature": 22
            }, {
              "date": 20111004,
              "temperature": 52
            }, {
              "date": 20111005,
              "temperature": 62
            }]
          }]
  ```

---

June 8th - outstanding fix

jsfiddle.net/497tmhu0/5 -- I am keen to merge the data input into a cleaner ONE source type situation. Also change the structure to a more -- label, value - naming convention then be specific in "temperature" -- like "San Francisco" should be a label ,x axis it appears broken or the ticks oddly formatted, text drop off occuring on the end of the lines -- possibly cut from the edges of the chart - maybe just a change in the margin -- "right: 55" –

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/497tmhu0/5/ I may have corrected the domain - but is there a better way to clean this up

Comment: ^ could someone take this version and complete the bounty - https://jsfiddle.net/497tmhu0/5/ -- I am keen to merge the data input into a cleaner ONE source type situation.
Also change the structure to a more -- label, value - naming convention then be specific in "temperature" -- like "San Francisco" should be a label
,x axis it appears broken or the ticks oddly formatted, text drop off occuring on the end of the lines -- possibly cut from the edges of the chart - maybe just a change in the margin -- "right: 55"